# Combine two buffers into a single write on Win32 pipe

Tags: c++, winapi, pipe, named-pipes, zeromq

I'm implementing the [ZeroMQ wire format](http://www.zeromq.org/whitepapers%3adesign-v01#toc5) over Win32 named pipes.  The format requires prepending a message with its size.  My interface looks like `send(std::vector<unsigned char>)` so the user has already allocated a buffer the exact size of their data, and I build the size header based on `vector.size()`.

Currently I'm sending the size header in a standalone write to the pipe.  But then, if the subsequent write of the actual message content fails, the data stream is left in a bad state where the receiver is expecting more data, but the sender considers that message failed.

I'd like to combine the size header and content into a single pipe write, so the header won't get through by itself.  But I'd like to avoid copying the `vector`'s content because it may be quite big. Is there any way to combine two buffers into a single Win32 pipe write?

If not, I can always add something like `unsigned char *getPipeBuffer(size_t size)` that allocates extra space for the header.  But it'd be nice to leave the interface untouched.

Answer (score 4):

Did you consider using the pipe with `PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE`? This way you get the message size for free and don't need to include it in the message itself.

When writing, the write operation only finishes when the whole message is written.

When reading, the read operation reads one message. Or, if the message doesn't fit in the pipe buffer, reads part of it, then reports there is more data waiting, and that you need to call it again to receive the rest of the message.

There is no need to pass the message size, because the receiver always knows when it finished reading one message.

Note that for pipe clients, it is necessary to change pipe read mode with a call to `SetNamedPipeHandleState`.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

My first response would have been to use [WriteFileGather](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but that comes with strict requirements on the alignment of buffers that you pass into the function which may be difficult to enforce, and after checking  the documentation it seems that this may not work with pipes at all, although I don't see why it wouldn't.

I think doing two distinct writes, one for the size and one for the data should be fine. You ask what will happen if the second write fails and the stream is left in some inconsistent state, where the other end expects more data. But even a single write request may leave the pipe in such a state: WriteFile may, for example, write less bytes than requested, necessitating a second write and that second write may fail.

Comment: From documentation: *Each buffer must be at least the size of a system memory page and must be aligned on a system memory page size boundary.*  That definitely won't work because a ZeroMQ header is either 1 or 9 bytes.  I agree with your second paragraph though, I guess I'll need to be prepared for this kind of problem no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the page you're using as a reference says, at the start, "WARNING: This text is deprecated and refers to an old version of ØMQ. It remains here for historical interest. DO NOT USE THIS TO LEARN ØMQ."

This is not the 0MQ wire format. If you want the 0MQ wire format, it's on the RFC site at http://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:15.

Comment: Wow, thank you for bringing that to my attention.  Fortunately I'm only using this protocol internally and it doesn't need to match ZeroMQ.  But this is very good to know.  Do you know why they chose to change it?